# Secure Ubuntu Desktop for Php Developer

Tags: ubuntu, php, xampp, desktop

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 10.4.

I would like to keep the system completely secure so that it's not vulnerable to any sorts of hacks, attacks, viruses, malware etc.

All i want to do on this system is to do some php based development(running Xampp) and then upload the website when it's ready to my hosting server.

Is it possible and how to accomplish it?

And what can be done to keep track of any changes(just in case if there's a rare chance of that happening)  done to the sysytem ?

Somebody here would possibly have an helpful answer for me.

Comment: Vote to move this to SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

For **complete** security:

1. Unplug Ethernet.
2. Install Ubuntu and XAMPP from physical media.
3. Write software. Copy software to external media.
4. Upload software via some other network-connected computer.

(Well, even that's not *complete*, but it's about as close as you can get without a rottweiler, a gun, and physical access to the server at the datacenter).

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu 10.04 server in a virtual machine(such kvm or virtualbox) for php. Use unattended-upgrade for upgrade you system. Using a strong password. Do not install ssh. Use iptables,chroot and other method to hardened.